# how can I stop view Rotation in Specific View Not All The Views

Tags: ios, objective-c

i make app and have a lot of views 
How can i Stop rotate in  One View From My Views in app ??

Can I get Help

Comment: Elaborate your case, please.  Stop rotating in one view from my views in app?  What does that mean in English?  Post a picture if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the following function of the `UIViewCovtroller` or  which ever view controller you are using where your view is placed.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
   interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || 
   interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ||
   interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown );
}
```

Edit

For ios 6 and above use the below method

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;// return only the supported orientation
}
```

Comment: i do put also still rotate

Comment: can you please paste your code.so that i can see where its going wrong.

Comment: - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;// return only the supported orientation
}
@end

Comment: <#import "VRGViewController.h"



interface VRGViewController ()

end

implementation VRGViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
      x=0;
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    
    calendar = [[VRGCalendarView alloc] init];
    
    calendar.delegate=self;
    [self.view addSubview:calendar];
}>

Comment: -(void)calendarView:(VRGCalendarView *)calendarView switchedToMonth:(int)month targetHeight:(float)targetHeight animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if (month==[[NSDate date] month]) {
        NSArray *dates = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:5], nil];
        [calendarView markDates:dates];
    }
}

Comment: -(void)calendarView:(VRGCalendarView *)calendarView dateSelected:(NSDate *)date {
  

    
    if (x == 0  ) {
        date1 = date ; 
        NSLog(@"Selected date11 = %@",date1);
    }else if ((x = 1)){
    
        date2 = date;
        NSLog(@"Selected date22 = %@",date2);


    [calendar removeFromSuperview];
        [self scrollViewBuild];

    
}
        
        else 
    {
        [calendar removeFromSuperview];
}
 

    NSLog(@"out Here Finished ");
    x ++ ;
    


}

Comment: -(void) scrollViewBuild
{
    NSLog(@"am here in fun ");
    
    NSLog(@"Selected date1 after = %@",date1);
    NSLog(@"Selected date2 after = %@",date2);
    
    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
//    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
//    mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading;
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
    
    
    
}

Comment: - (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
// pre-iOS 6 support
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end

Comment: Are you adding `VRGViewController` as a subview to some other view?

Comment: If YES add the rotation methods mentioned in this answer to the view controller where you adding the view from `VRGViewController ` as a `subview`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TabViewController or NavigationController where some of the views are not  returning UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait it will not work. Either change code so that all ViewControllers return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait.

Alternately you can use this category (if using UINavigationController)

```
@interface UINavigationController (RotationPortrait)
    -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations;
@end

@implementation UINavigationController (RotationPortrait)
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
@end
```

Comment: i do put also still rotate

Comment: What did you tried ? Explain more in your question so that anyone here can help.

Comment: i use all of the above but not work , but now am try to delete this from app delegate (the next comment ) it stop rotate but stop all the app . so the question now how can i stop specific View not all the app views . i.e (how to override this method in specific view )

Comment: - (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait  | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}